# Overlapping Textures using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, snapchat

I want to overlap one texture on top of another, at a given point, using OpenCV asset for unity engine. 
What I basically mean by that is I want to make a snapchat like application wherein a dog nose is placed on top of the person's nose in the picture. I have managed to find the point where it needs to be overlapped.
Seamless cloning feature is NOT something which can help as it modifies the texture. I simply want it to overlap.
[Something like this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myGPX.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some snippets of what you have tried? What errors did you face when trying to solve the problem? Welcome to StackOverflow! You may also want to take the [tour] and have a look at [ask]

Comment: You can look at the function _addWeighted(overlay, alpha, output, 1 - alpha,0, output)_. With overlay your dog face image and alpha the transparency.